# pg_ctl error when using pg_upgrade

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, postgresql-10, postgresql-12

We are attempting to upgrade Postgres 10.10 to 12.4 using pg_upgrade on a Windows 2016 Server machine using the command

> "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/bin/pg_upgrade.exe”
> --old-datadir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/data"
> --new-datadir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/data"
> --old-bindir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/bin"
> --new-bindir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/bin"

It fails with the error

> could not get pg_ctl version output from "C:/Program
> Files/PostgreSQL/10/bin/pg_ctl" --version Failure, exiting

Running pg_ctl – V from the command line correctly identifies version 10.10.

This is on a sandbox machine but both installs have been tested and are connectable, writeable and readable.
The command is being run under the ‘postgres’ Windows user from an empty, writeable directory.
Both Services are stopped.

I haven’t had any success Googling the error, so does anyone know the cause and how to get past it?

Thank you

Comment: Putting the data directory into `c:\Program Files` is a bad idea to begin with. I wouldn't be surprised if your problem is caused with the extremely tight permissions on that directory (and everything below it)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I concur that that is a bad location, but `pg_ctl --version` doesn't touch the data directory.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  The postgres user has full permissions to Program Files and also specifically to the data directory.  Is that not enough?                                     
The production environment has Data on a separate drive but the test machine only has one so I left Data in the default location.  Should I try moving it somewhere else on c:?

Comment: UPDATE:  I did move the data directories and re ran the command which resulted in the same failure.